Elephant ground-borne communication: which is the most important production method?
Elephants are documented to use ground-based (solid-based) communication.
A lot of research seems to focus on how these sounds can be perceived. But what is the most important method for them to produce these solid-borne signals?
I would imagine that the feet have the best coupling to the ground, though it may be that vocalisations can also be transmitted through the trunk into the ground at sufficient energy?
In the 2019 paper Vibrational Communication in Elephants: A Case for Bone Conduction I read:

Elephant low-frequency (20 Hz) rumble vocalizations are generated at
such high amplitudes (on the order of 90–100 decibels SPL at 5 m) that
they couple with the ground through the feet and propagate along the
surface of the earth [...] The interactive pattern of vocalizations
that occurs during the “let’s go” rumble volley during the time when a
family group, or bonded group of males, leaves the waterhole results
in [a signal of high energy and duration].

but also:

For example, an elephant mock charge ends in a foot-stomping behavior
that generates vibrations with [sufficent energy to propagate far]

For a non-expert it is a little hard to be clear: is there one dominant/important production mechanism they are using, or do they perhaps use multiple mechanisms together?
